# Calculating band depth image for M3 data

Tags: remote-sensing, digital-image-processing

I am working with chandrayaan M3 hyper spectral data. I need to create a band depth image for identifying mineral abundances. How do i calculate the continuum reflectance value for producing a band depth image? Is that a constant value for the whole band or should i calculate the continuum reflectance for each pixel of the band. The formula given for calculating band depth is BD = 1- Reflectance at a specific wavelength(R1450)/Continuum reflectance at that wavelength(R1450i).
[image: Example- Band depth calculation for 1450 nm wavelenth]

Comment: How can we calculate band center in Envi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many methods for creating band depth images. So, it depends on the method that you are using. if you want simple Band depth analysis, you can use

[image]

I'm working on ENVI software and it has a tool named Band Math. using that tool and the expression, we can get Band Depth Image.

Comment: Thanks @djhawk vek. Please clarify this. Band math does a pixel by pixel analysis. Should i calculate Continuum reflectance value(Rc) for each pixel as each pixel has a varied spectral signature? or is Rc value is a constant for each wavelength?

Comment: Rc value varies for each pixel. And what Band Math does here is, it applies the 'math expression' for the selected bands to all the selected pixels or simply the pixels of the spatially sub-setted region. If you want a Depth vs wavelength profile, select all the available bands of Reflectance spectra for Rb and that of Continuum Reflectance for Rc.

Comment: For Continuum Spectra, you can use  ' Br/Bcr ' in Band math. Where Br is the Reflectance Spectra and Bcr is the Continuum removed Reflectance.   And Continuum removed Reflectance can be obtained from Continuum removal tool provided in ENVI